# Swift Optional Binding with Constants, and Scope

Tags: ios, swift, scope

I'm trying to understand why the following is valid in Swift.  I'm assuming it has to do with the way things are scoped in Swift.

```
let name = "test" //assigns "test" to name
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName { //assigns "John Appleseed" to name
  let name = "no error" //assigns "no error" to name
  greeting = "Hello, \(name)" //assigns "Hello, no error" to greeting
}
println(name) //prints "test"
```

What I believe is happening is this is creating 3 separate name constants all in different scopes.  The first let name is in the global scope.  Then the optional binding let name is another scope, and then within the if the let name is another scope.  Then the final print goes back out to the global scope.

Comment: your understanding is correct, just rephrase your last sentence to read "Then the final println uses the only name in the same scope, which is the first one" as you called it, the global scope

Answer (score 0):

You have already understood:)
It uses the first variable it finds with such name, starting from the inner scope and going up.